# Print Variable Name with CVS Input

Tags: php, forms, csv, variables

I am passing field inputs to a .csv sheet, but I was wondering if it was possible to have the variable name print along with the value?

Here is how I'm printing to the .cvs:

PHP

```
<?php
$csvdata = $firstName . ", " . $lastName . ", " . $homeAddress . ", " . $homeAddressTwo . ", " . $city . ", " . $province . ", " . $postalCode . ", " . $homePhone . ", " . $personalEmail . ", " . $confirmEmail . ", " . $oectaNumber . ", " . $memberStatus . ", " . $teacherTraining . ", " . $teachingYears . "," . $employmentHistoryValues;
$fp = fopen("formdata.csv", "a");
if($fp)
    {
    fwrite($fp, $csvdata . "\n");
    fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

Here is what I am wanting it to look like:

```
Array ( [0] => WLU [1] => Math [2] => 2016 )
```

Here is how I am process the viariables:

```
$educationHistoryValues = "";
foreach(print_r($_POST["educationHistory"]) as $educationValue)
{
    $educationHistoryValues .= $educationValue;
}
```

Input Data:

```
<div id="educationHistory" name="educationHistory[]">
<input type="text" class="three-lines" name="educationHistory[]" id="educationInstitution_1" placeholder="Institution" onblur="this.placeholder='Institution'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onkeyup="checkPage2()" />

<input type="text" class="three-lines" name="educationHistory[]" id="degreeFromInstitution_1" placeholder="Degree/Diploma" onblur="this.placeholder='Degree/Diploma'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onkeyup="checkPage2()" />

<input type="date" class="three-lines" name="educationHistory[]" id="educationalDates_1" />
                            <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addEducation()" />
                        </div><!--end educationHistory Div -->                
                    </div><!--end of education div-->
```

In the CSV document itself, the results are fairly easy to decipher but the form I am drawing from has a bunch of dynamic inputs that will generate multidimensional arrays and some of the inputs are textareas, so I wanted to test out this theory.

Comment: What output result do you exactly expect?

Comment: Currently it prints just the input result in a specific cell.  When I print_r the entire form it gave a fairly neat layout like this:  [memberStatus] => good, where Member Status was the variable name and good was the user input.  Would something like that be possible?

Comment: Where are the variables coming from? Which of them in your example is dynamic (you are hardcoding them which to me means you know the dynamics?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example create a header csv row with the column names. You can achieve this by:

```
  $csv = 'col1, col2.....'.PHP_EOL;
  foreach ($data as $item) {
      $csv .= $item['val1'].','.$item['val2'].....PHP_EOL;
  }
  // write $csv to file
```

This will be helpful if you open the csv file in excel or open office.

But if you want to key name + value:

```
  foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
      $csv .= $key.'=>'.$item['val1'].',';
  }
```

This is example for one dimensionsl array. If you have multi dimensional you will have nested loop instead.

Comment: This is neat!  In the case of a nested loop how would I integrate that with your second example.  For example, let's say item1 is a normal single input, but item 2 is a collection of three inputs that can be dynamically generated.  How would that look code wise?

Comment: Can you add the dump of this nested array in the question + the way you want the output to look like

Comment: Very new to php, what is "the dump" see above for amend

Comment: var_dump($data); and by $data I mean the array that holds your data

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I just edited my intial question it is there

Comment: and what about the input data ?

Comment: See above.  It may be that I am not dumping properly but I know the inuts are collecting

Comment: You added your input elements not the real input data. You can now paste all of your html form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126263/discussion-between-theodore-steiner-and-krasipenkov).